# Know the address of a variable in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am starting to learn to debug C programs with Visual Studio 2008. When running in debug mode, how is it possible to know the address of a initialized variable? I choose to watch it but can only know about the value. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can type in a `&` in front of the variable, which will display it's address.